# providing static IP to docker compose container (and connect to it with python socket)

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I created a docker-compose file and runned a container with a static IP address (10.5.0.5) on it, The container is running a python script that uses socket to listen on the given ip address and port. This is successfully running without any errors. Now I want to be able to connect to that ip with other python script using socket outside of that docker file.
this python script is on other location in my computer.
Can someone help me achive that goal?

> there is a Dockerfile inside 'files' folder that running the python file

> When connecting to '127.0.0.1:4000' IP everything working fine.
> I want that you will need to connect via '10.5.0.5:4000' address

**dokcer-compose file:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  node1:
    container_name: node1
    build: ./files # building the Dockerfile and running the python script
    volumes:
      - ./files:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5

networks:
  vpcbr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
         gateway: 10.5.0.1
```

**node1 python code**

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 4000))
    sock.listen(1)
    csock, addr = sock.accept()
    csock.sendall(b'hey')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to your docker from outside (at least from another computer). You need to connect using the IP of the computer running docker. To find out the address use "ip a" or "ifconfig" for Linux or "ipconfig" for Windows.

Also, to make your script able to listen outside requests you can set:

```
 sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 4000))
```

This will make your script listen for requests from all interfaces.

To connect to node1 from local you can use "node1:4000"

Comment: I tried this and its working if I am connecting with 127.0.0.1 ip address.
I want to connect via the ip I gave the container under the ipv4_address (10.5.0.5)

Comment: I am running the code on the same computer. simplest server client python scripts using sockets. just insted of connecting with localhost to the client I want to connect to that code with another ip like a real service on the internet (simulate a real computer that is outside of my network).